# Replacing values greater than a number in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, database, pandas

I have a large dataframe which looks as:

```
df1['A'].ix[1:3]
2017-01-01 02:00:00    [33, 34, 39]
2017-01-01 03:00:00    [3, 43, 9]
```

I want to replace each element greater than 9 with 11.

So, the desired output for above example is:

```
df1['A'].ix[1:3]
2017-01-01 02:00:00    [11, 11, 11]
2017-01-01 03:00:00    [3, 11, 9]
```

Edit:

My actual dataframe has about 20,000 rows and each row has list of size 2000.

Is there a way to use `numpy.minimum` function for each row? I assume that it will be faster than `list comprehension` method?

Comment: So values are not in list?  Ithink `df[df > 9] = 11` solution is wrong. Or something missing?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can use `apply` with `list comprehension`:

```
df1['A'] = df1['A'].apply(lambda x: [y if y <= 9 else 11 for y in x])
print (df1)
                                A
2017-01-01 02:00:00  [11, 11, 11]
2017-01-01 03:00:00    [3, 11, 9]
```

Faster solution is first convert to `numpy array` and then use [`numpy.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
a = np.array(df1['A'].values.tolist())
print (a)
[[33 34 39]
 [ 3 43  9]]

df1['A'] = np.where(a > 9, 11, a).tolist()
print (df1)
                                A
2017-01-01 02:00:00  [11, 11, 11]
2017-01-01 03:00:00    [3, 11, 9]
```

Comment: This method replaces nan values with the number following else which is not something I want to do.

Answer (score 59):

Very simply : `df[df > 9] = 11`

Answer (score 37):

I know this is an old post, but pandas now supports [`DataFrame.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) directly. In your example:

```py
df.where(df <= 9, 11, inplace=True)
```

Please note that pandas' `where` is different than [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). In pandas, when the `condition == True`, the current value in the dataframe is used. When `condition == False`, the other value is taken.

EDIT:

You can achieve the same for just a column with [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```py
df['A'].where(df['A'] <= 9, 11, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 26):

You can use numpy indexing, accessed through the `.values` function.

`df['col'].values[df['col'].values > x] = y`

where you are replacing any value greater than x with the value of y.

So for the example in the question:

`df1['A'].values[df1['A'] > 9] = 11`

Comment: This was the best solution I could find that worked as expected.

Answer (score 6):

I came for a solution to replacing each element larger than h by 1 else 0, which has the simple solution:

```
df = (df > h) * 1
```

(This does not solve the OP's question as all df <= h are replaced by 0.)

Comment: Why do you write it as an answer, if it doesn't answer the OP's question?

Comment: Because the title (which led me and potentially others to come here) is imprecise and could imply this answer.