# Pandas set value in a column equal to 5% quantile if they are smaller than that

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, quantile

Generating data

```
random.seed(42)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(len(date_rng), 3)),
                  columns=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                 index= date_rng)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], df.shape, p=[.35, .65]).astype(bool)
df[mask] = np.nan
```

I want to do the following operation: calculate the 5% quantile of each column, then compare the value of each cell in that column with the calculated quantile: if they are smaller, set them to the 5% quantile of the column.

I have read those questions

[Pandas DataFrame: replace all values in a column, based on condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31511997/pandas-dataframe-replace-all-values-in-a-column-based-on-condition/31512025)

[Replacing values greater than a number in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757977/replacing-values-greater-than-a-number-in-pandas-dataframe)

and come up with my solution:

```
df[df < df.quantile(q=0.05, axis=0)] = df.quantile(q=0.05, axis=0)
```

but it's not working, because I'm trying to replace each value with a series. How can I solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get quantile by [`DataFrame.quantile`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html) of all columns and pass it to [`DataFrame.clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html).

```
np.random.seed(42)
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/08/2018', freq='H')
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,size=(len(date_rng), 3)),
                  columns=['data1', 'data2', 'data3'],
                 index= date_rng)
mask = np.random.choice([1, 0], df.shape, p=[.35, .65]).astype(bool)
print (df)
                     data1  data2  data3
2018-01-01 00:00:00      6      3      7
2018-01-01 01:00:00      4      6      9
2018-01-01 02:00:00      2      6      7
2018-01-01 03:00:00      4      3      7
2018-01-01 04:00:00      7      2      5
                   ...    ...    ...
2018-01-07 20:00:00      7      6      4
2018-01-07 21:00:00      0      6      6
2018-01-07 22:00:00      8      2      8
2018-01-07 23:00:00      0      0      3
2018-01-08 00:00:00      8      5      2
```

For testing is used different quantile:

```
print (df.quantile(q=0.55))
data1    6.0
data2    4.0
data3    5.0
Name: 0.55, dtype: float64

df = df.clip(lower=df.quantile(q=0.55), axis=1)
print (df)
                     data1  data2  data3
2018-01-01 00:00:00      6      4      7
2018-01-01 01:00:00      6      6      9
2018-01-01 02:00:00      6      6      7
2018-01-01 03:00:00      6      4      7
2018-01-01 04:00:00      7      4      5
                   ...    ...    ...
2018-01-07 20:00:00      7      6      5
2018-01-07 21:00:00      6      6      6
2018-01-07 22:00:00      8      4      8
2018-01-07 23:00:00      6      4      5
2018-01-08 00:00:00      8      5      5
```