# How to replace values greater than 30 for missing value?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to set all the values that are greater than 30 in a dataset as missing values.
My dataset is huge, but here is the format of my df:

| date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 20 | 5 |
| 01/02/2021 | 15 | 20 |
| 01/01/2022 | 17 | 30 |
| 01/01/2023 | 30 | 40 |

expected result:

| date | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 | 20 | 5 |
| 01/02/2021 | 15 | 20 |
| 01/01/2022 | 17 | NAN |
| 01/01/2023 | NAN | NAN |

Would be also nice to count how many of the values are bigger than 30, in this case, 3.

As asked below, I have tried the code:

df= df.apply(lambda x: [y if y <= 30 else NAN for y in x])

Output:

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Comment: he said "example of my df". Can assume that this is a pandas dataframe. Read before downvote.

Comment: also, this question has already been answered :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43757977/replacing-values-greater-than-a-number-in-pandas-dataframe. If you can't get to the solution yourself please post part of your code in your question :)

Comment: Huh, `df[df >= 30] = np.nan`? `df[df >= 30].sum().sum()`?

Comment: It is a pandas dataframe.

Comment: @timgeb I get the error "TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' "

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
df[df[["A", "B"]].astype(int)>=30] = pd.NA
```

Comment: In my original dataframe I have a very huge amount of columns, so I cannot write the name of each one in my command. I have tried:
df3 [df3 [ [ ] ].astype (int)>=3] = pd.NA
which returns " TypeError: Cannot do inplace boolean setting on mixed-types with a non np.nan value"

Comment: 'columns = df.columns[df.columns!="date"]' and after 'df[df[columns].astype(int)>=30] = pd.NA', but it will work only if all other columns except "date" are numeric columns

Comment: The first line of code worked. Even though all my other columns are numeric, they contain some values non-numeric (NAN), because of that, the second line of code results in "IntCastingNaNError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer". Any idea on how to get around it?

Comment: Ok sorry for that it think that in this case you must cast to 'float' instead of 'int'. Try and let me know. Thanks

Comment: I have tried it, but it returns me "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis!" . I do not understand what this error means. Do I have duplicated column names? I run " df3.columns.duplicated().any() ", and returned me "True"

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the values in individual columns greater than or equal to 30 with 'NAN', and then count them.

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.A[df.A >= 30] = 'NAN'
df.B[df.B >= 30] = 'NAN'
print(df)
print('Values >= 30 in column A =', df.A.value_counts()['NAN'])
print('Values >= 30 in column B =', df.B.value_counts()['NAN'])
```

Comment: I have a huge amount of columns, and so I cannot do it like that.